# use multi line arrow function in a accessor method in laravel models

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add an accessor to a model in laravel where I can change the format of the created_at field to a jalali date via [Verta](https://github.com/hekmatinasser/verta) Package.

I know that we can use the arrow function like this :

```
protected function createdAt(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn (string $value) =>
            $vertaDate = Verta::instance($value);
            $vertaDate->format('Y/m/d H:i:s')
        ,
    );
}
```

It needs to use the multi expression in the get method arrow function.

I'm looking for the best approach for that.

Comment: As far as I know, you can only use single line expressions in an Arrow function.

Comment: Very well, but how can we write the method if we have to use multi-line commands in accessors?

Comment: Could you format the Vertadate without saving it to a variable? That would save you one line

Comment: Suppose I could do that. But really, in a similar situation, what can we do if we need some operation to generate results?

Comment: Then you would just have to use a regular anonymous function instead of an arrow function.
As such:
```function () { } ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write multiple expressions in PHP arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65903832/how-to-write-multiple-expressions-in-php-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected function createdAt(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn (string $value): string => (Verta::instance($value))->format('Y/m/d H:i:s')
        ,
    );
}
```

This is how you can code it with short arrow function.

Or you can use https://stackoverflow.com/users/15040689/oskar-mikael suggestion if one line code can't solve it.

Comment: I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.